# Using class to draw shapes in turtle

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am supposed to develop classes for line segments, circles, and rectangles in which each shape should contain a Turtle object and color to allow it to be drawn in a Turtle graphics window. I will have one main Shape class in which the circle, rectangle, and line classes are subclasses of it. What i have so far is

```
class Shape(object):
"""Represents a Shape"""

def __init__(self, width, height):
   self._width = width
   self._height = height

def rectangle(self):
```

What i want to achieve is the user inputs a number for width and height, and based on that, turtle will draw a rectangle using those. Then other shapes will also be drawn using those number for scale. So for example if i input

```
Shape (100, 150)
```

then a rectangle with a width of 100 and height of 150 will be drawn and perhaps a circle with radius of 1/2 the height will be drawn.

I am stumped at this point though. I can't seem to figure out what to do next to have turtle actually draw the rectangle. Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

Well there are relatively simple solutions to each of these but since it is an assignment I won't give you the exact code just a general idea of what you need to do.

For the circle:

Turtle has a circle function that looks like `turtle.circle(n)` where n is the radius

For the rectangle:

You have 2 good options:

1. You could use 90 degree turns, such as right or left, and forwards with your lengths to draw the rectangle.
2. You can calculate the four corners' x and y coordinates and use the goto or setpos functions to go to those corners in order

For the line:

Use the goto or setpos to go to a location making a line or use forward to draw a straight line in the direction that you are facing.

Comment: Thanks for the reply however, i already know all of this stuff. What im asking about is more for using classes to draw it. Like i'm unsure how to put it in my code for the subclass so that when i type in Shape (100, 150) it will draw a rectangle with those parameters.

Comment: You will need to make methods (like functions in classes) and have one method or more for each shape. You can then put your code in each of these methods and then call them in the class init. You should not need different classes for each shape.

Answer (score 0):

I'm working on the exact same problem now:
Under shape make a subclass for each of your different kinds of shapes.
So when using the class in other code it would look like:

```
shape.rectangle(width,height)<<<(depending on how you're going to have it draw the thing)
```

Solution:

```
class Shape(self):
#then
def rectangle(self, width, height):
#instructions for making a rectangle with width and height in this case
```