# Shape Class implementation in Python with actual drawn square?

Tags: python, class, draw, shapes

I have the following code that creates a shape class, and I have two questions that I would appreciate answers for:
1. When the following code is run, the output is:

```
>>> 
100
100
None
>>>
```

**What is the "None" at the end, and how can I get rid of this output?**

**2. I would ideally like to be able to DRAW (in the output screen) a square**. I do not wish to use pygame. I did wonder about whether it would be possible to integrate turtle to do this, but don't know how to get started? Any suggestions for the method that would do this using turtle, or any other genius suggestion?

```
from turtle import*
class Shape:
    #self is how we refer to things in the clas from within itself. .self is the first parameter in any function defined inside a class
    #to access functions and variables inside the class, their name must be preceded with self and a full-stop (e.g. self.variable_name)
    def __init__(self,x,y):
        self.x=x #the shape has the attribute x (width)
        self.y=y #the shape has the attribute y (height)

    description="The shape has not yet been brought into being"
    author="No one has yet claimed authorship of this shape"

    def area(self):
        return self.x*self.y
    def perimeter(self):
        return 2*self.x+2*self.y
    def describe(self,text):
        self.description =text
    def authorName(self,text):
        self.author=text
    def scaleSize(self,scale):
        self.x=self.x*scale
        self.y=self.y*scale
    def print(self):
        print(self.x)
        print(self.y)


square=Shape(100,100)
print(square.print())
```

I might add that there is a similar question on SO but no specific or helpful answer

[Using class to draw shapes in turtle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34047286/using-class-to-draw-shapes-in-turtle)

UPDATE:

I tried something like this, but cannot get it working. I think I need to initialise turtle somewhere in the constructor - but where and how

```
from turtle import*
class Shape:
    #self is how we refer to things in the clas from within itself. .self is the first parameter in any function defined inside a class
    #to access functions and variables inside the class, their name must be preceded with self and a full-stop (e.g. self.variable_name)
    def __init__(self,x,y):
        self.x=x #the shape has the attribute x (width)
        self.y=y #the shape has the attribute y (height)


    description="The shape has not yet been brought into being"
    author="No one has yet claimed authorship of this shape"

    def area(self):
        return self.x*self.y
    def perimeter(self):
        return 2*self.x+2*self.y
    def describe(self,text):
        self.description =text
    def authorName(self,text):
        self.author=text
    def scaleSize(self,scale):
        self.x=self.x*scale
        self.y=self.y*scale
    def print(self,shapename):
        print("This shape is a", shapename, "with dimensions:>",self.x,"by",self.y)
    def draw(self):
        turtle.forward(self.x)
        turtle.left(90)
        turtle.forward(se.f.x)
        turtle.left(90)
        turtle.forward(self.y)
        turtle.left(90)
        turtle.forward(self.y)
        turtle.left(90)



square=Shape(100,100)
square.print("square")
print("The perimeter is:",square.perimeter())
print(square.draw())
```

Comment: `print(square.print())` This line is generating None on console as function is not returning anything. To remove it just remove outer print() and keep remaining. i.e. `square.print()`

Comment: Thank you! Any thoughts on the second quesion!

Comment: Am on it :) I will update in sometime

Comment: Thank you! Added an update. (the code for draw is not correct) but that's the idea. I don't know where to get the class to recognise turtle......

Comment: Warning, by doing `from turtle import *` and `class Shape:` you are redefining turtle's own `Shape` class!  You can confirm this by printing `id(Shape)` before and after your `class Shape:` (re)definition.  You should either restrict your import, `import turtle` or `from turtle import Turtle, Screen` or else rename your `Shape` class to something else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
from turtle import*
class Shape:
    canvas = Screen() # creating object of screen class
    canvas.setup(800,800) # this will setup window on screen with dimension 800x800

    turtle_obj = Turtle() # creating object of turtle class which will be used to plot square on window

    #self is how we refer to things in the clas from within itself. .self is the first parameter in any function defined inside a class
    #to access functions and variables inside the class, their name must be preceded with self and a full-stop (e.g. self.variable_name)
    def __init__(self,x,y):
        self.x=x #the shape has the attribute x (width)
        self.y=y #the shape has the attribute y (height)

    description="The shape has not yet been brought into being"
    author="No one has yet claimed authorship of this shape"

    def area(self):
        return self.x*self.y
    def perimeter(self):
        return 2*self.x+2*self.y
    def describe(self,text):
        self.description =text
    def authorName(self,text):
        self.author=text
    def scaleSize(self,scale):
        self.x=self.x*scale
        self.y=self.y*scale

    def print(self):
        print self.x
        print self.y
        # now we are referring to class object turtle using self.turtle_obj and 
        # calling forward() function which will move plotting cursor in forward direction 
        # upto x pixels and left() will rotate direction by 90 degree 
        self.turtle_obj.forward(self.x)
        self.turtle_obj.left(90)
        self.turtle_obj.forward(self.y)
        self.turtle_obj.left(90)
        self.turtle_obj.forward(self.x)
        self.turtle_obj.left(90)
        self.turtle_obj.forward(self.y)
        self.turtle_obj.left(90)




square=Shape(100,100)
square.print()
```

1. print(square.print()) This line is generating None on console as function is not returning anything. To remove it just remove outer print() and keep remaining. i.e. square.print()
2. Yes it is possible and I made little changes in your code and now it should create square on screen.

Comment: Thank you! The turtle functionality is there now!!!!!! BUT....it always draws a square, and doesn't recognise the input parameters.

Comment: Can I simply change the 'forward' variables (e.g. 50) to self.x and self.y etc

Comment: @MissComputing I have now made changes so now it will make use of user input and 90 is angle by which it changes direction. I hope it works for you :)

Comment: Wonderful. Thank you!

Comment: As a last request, if possible, could you comment the code pertaining to the addition of turtle. So that users understand its implementation. How is that part of the class....etc (e.g. canvas = Screen()
    canvas.setup(800,800)
    turtle_obj = Turtle()")

Comment: @MissComputing am not getting what is exactly you asked ? can you rephrase please

Comment: Ah, I just meant could you explain what is happening in the part where you initialise turtle. I can't see or understand how it all fits in with the class or how the class "sees" it. Basically, if you could just comment thoroughly your excellent answer above, that would be hugely helpful for many!

Comment: so turtle object and canvas etc are not being implemented/created as part of the __init__ constructor, so don't understand how /why they are where they are..

Comment: @MissComputing I have added couple of comments in code itself. 

1.  turtle and canvas objects are created as soon as class object is created but they can be created inside constructor too there is absolute no necessity to keep it outside. 

2. Thank you so much for kind words and I hope solution works for you.